# How Can I Replicate & Register a Widget from the Child Theme

Tags: widgets, child-theme, register-sidebar

I'm working with a WordPress theme which features a widget that uses the Google Maps API to display a map in the footer of the site.  It works great, but seeing that we have two buildings, I would like to add a second map to the footer.  Simply adding another copy of the widget in the Admin panel doesn't seem to be working - the two maps are displayed but doesn't show the address nor zoom in to it - I just see an identical display of the world map.

The parent theme is at **../dealership-deluxe** and child theme is at **../dealership-deluxe-child-theme** respectively, and "**Footer4_Widget**" is the name of the footer that I want to replicate.

Given the above paths and identify of the footer, here's what I've tried so far (in addition to the previous):

`grep -r "Footer4" /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dealership-deluxe`

The above command revealed the following:

```
../dealership-deluxe/sidebars/register-sidebars.php:     register_widget('Footer4_Widget');
../dealership-deluxe/sidebars/register-sidebars.php:class Footer4_Widget extends WP_Widget {
```

Which led me to mirror the path from the parent and create a "Footer5_Widget" - assuming that this would create a new widget and allow the generation of the second map.

So I issued `grep -r "Footer5" /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dealership-deluxe-child-theme` and it revealed the following:

```
../dealership-deluxe/sidebars/register-sidebars.php:     register_widget('Footer5_Widget');
../dealership-deluxe/sidebars/register-sidebars.php:class Footer5_Widget extends WP_Widget {
```

However, this didn't happen.  In fact, the new widget doesn't even show up in the WordPress Admin panel for selection.  What's interesting though is that if I create the new widget within the parent theme, the new widget shows up in the WordPress Admin panel BUT still the maps don't generate - just shows the worldmap for both locations.

I've already reached out to the theme developer for assistance, but haven't heard back hence my reaching out for help here.  Ideally, I would like very much to make this change in the Child Theme and not the parent.  Please forgive any obvious rookie mistakes, as I'm still learning.  Nonetheless, any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Here's what the footer looks like when working:**
[image: Footer4_Widget from Parent Theme]

**Here's what the footer looks like when I create the copy:**
[image]

Comment: this sounds like a question you should ask the author of the parent theme. it sounds like its widget implementation is buggy or lacking

Comment: Yes I have done that, by way of a support ticket. just waiting on a reply.  Figured I'd ask on here as well in case anyone had run into a similar issue and could lend a hand.